# Adding custom jar (with dependencies) dependency into pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have used maven clean build to generate jar (along with - jar with dependencies) from some X maven project. The following jars have been added to my local maven repo.

  org-utility

- 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

  - _remote.repositories
  - maven-metadata-local
  - org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  - org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
  - org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- maven-metadata-local

So, I was able to retrieve jar "retrieve org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" into another maven project 'Y' as a dependency. Below is code which i added in pom.xml and it was working fine.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-utility</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

But my question here is that how to retrieve this jar "org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" into same maven project 'Y' as a depenency.

I was using the below code in pom.xml and getting errors like Missing and Failed to read artifact in eclipse neon IDE.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.org.utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-utility</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also I see new folder gets created under maven repo as below.

  org-utility

- 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies

  - org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.pom.lastUpdated

Text in the file org-utility-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.pom.lastUpdated is as below

> NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can
>   be changed without prior notice. Thu Mar 16 19:58:17 IST 2017
>   @default-internal-http://localhost:3001/repository/internal/.lastUpdated=1489674496370
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1489674497497
>   http://localhost:3001/repository/internal/.error=Could not transfer
>   artifact
>   com.org.utils:org-utility:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies
>   from/to internal (http://localhost:3001/repository/internal/):
>   Connection refused: connect
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=

Please help me out from this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you want this jar? refer the "normal" jar and all other dependencies will be added to your new project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to reference this jar, you should probably use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.org.utils</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-utility</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
</dependency>
```

But *usually*, you do not want to reference this jar because it would screw up the Maven dependency mechanism if you mix it with other dependencies. On the other hand, if you use the jar without the dependencies Maven will do the dependency resolution for you.

As a side note: To overwrite the non-resolved "lastUpdated" files, start your Maven build with `-u`

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JF Meier , Adding classifier resolved my issue, However could you please explain the steps for dependency resolution as well (like how we can add all other dependencies into new project) if in case I want to use normal jar itself, because there are lot of other dependencies were used in X project which i suppose to use in Y project, instead of adding all once again in Y's pom, along with the custom classes generated in jar.

Comment: If X has a dependency on A and you declare a dependency on X, then you automatically get A as well. This is the transitive dependency resolution mechanism of Maven. You do not need to copy dependencies. BTW: If you like my answer, please upvote and accept.